# mysql dependencies installation problem

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, mysql, dependencies

I am reinstalling mysql on a test server with Ubuntu 14.04 before I hadn't had any problems reinstalling it. When I reinstall it I do the following:

```
use apt-get purge and remove on mysql-server-5.5 and mysql-server
clear all mysql related files
use `apt-get clear`, `autoclear`, `autoremove`
reinstall mysql-server with `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` after that installs properly I install the mysql-server
```

Now I am stuck with the dependencies.

```
when I use `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` this shows up Depends: mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
when I use `apt-get install mysql-server-client-5.5` this shows up Depends: libdbd-mysql-perl (>= 1.2202) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
when I use `apt-get install libdbd-mysql-perl` this shows up Depends: perlapi-5.14.2
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

when I check the perl version with perl -v I have 5.18.2 do I need to downgrade my perl or update something? I made sure everything else is updated (`apt-get update`) and upgrade (`apt-get upgrade`)

Answer (score 0):

solved it T_T just used `apt-get install perl-base=5.14.2-6ubuntu2.4` then everything else follows